# How to use curl in unity by changing curl to WWWform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to authenticate to use a specific map API, which is the authentication method curl.

But I don't know how to use curl by changing it to form.

```
curl "https://naveropenapi.apigw.ntruss.com/map-static/v2/raster?w=300&h=300&center=127.1054221,37.3591614&level=16" \
-H "X-NCP-APIGW-API-KEY-ID: {client id}" \
-H "X-NCP-APIGW-API-KEY: {client secret}" -v
```

Please teach me the way.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the headers for the request. You can do so by using a Dictonary.

```
Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
headers.Add("X-NCP-APIGW-API-KEY-ID", "{client id}");
headers.Add("X-NCP-APIGW-API-KEY", "{client secret}");

WWW www = new WWW("https://naveropenapi.apigw.ntruss.com/map-static/v2/raster?w=300&h=300&center=127.1054221,37.3591614&level=16", null, headers);
yield return www;

Debug.Log(www.text);
```

Comment: Might want to clarify the need for StartCoroutine as well, to explain the `yield return www`